# Query that returns me rows that have a specific Hexadecimal

Tags: sql, oracle

How can i make a query that returns me all the row where ent_name have a spefific HEX value that i know i can get using the function - UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2(HEXTORAW('C253')?

This dont work for me:

```
select * from table where ent_name like (UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2(HEXTORAW('C253')))
```

Can you help please?

Answer (score 1):

A first guess, do you forget the '%' chars in your like statement because the HEX sequence is only part of ent_name?

```
select * from table where ent_name like '%'||(UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2(HEXTORAW('C253')))|| '%'
```